# Finding Debt/Equity Ratio with Market Value of Equity

Tags: yahoo-finance, ratio

I'm trying to find out the debt/equity ratio (percentage) for various stocks. I'm keen to know the ratio based on the market value of equities, not the book value.

I was told that Google Finance and Yahoo Finance have this number, albeit I couldn't find it.

For example, this page on Yahoo: http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=TSM has two statistics under Balance Sheet:

- Total Debt/Equity (mrq)
- Current Ratio (mrq)

Neither of these are expressed as a percentage. Where can I find the debt/equity ratio, as a percentage, with the market value of equity? (Or, where can I find enough data to calculate this)?

This is of course for any arbitrary stock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to calculate the ratio you are looking for, just divide **total debt** by the **market capitalization** of the stock. Both values can be found on the link you provided. The market capitalization is the market value of equity.

Comment: What about Google Finance's page: viewing a stock, then Financials, then Balance Sheet? It has "total debt" and "total equity." Are these book or market values?

Comment: Total equity in the balance sheet is book value. Market capitalization is the market value of the company`s equity.